# data preprocessing: keras layers vs tf.image.resize

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to preprocess images from the 'oxford_flowers102' dataset in tensorflow 2 (version 2.3.0) to train an inception v3 network. I have found two ways to resize the images, both are working,it seems that both generate the same output. I do not understand which solution is better for my task. Can you explain which way is better to use?

1. with tf.image.resize

```
   IMAGE_RES = 229
   dataset, dataset_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
   dataset_info
   test_set, training_set, validation_set = dataset['test'], dataset['train'], dataset['validation']

   get_label_name = dataset_info.features['label'].int2str
   image, label = next(iter(training_set))
   image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMAGE_RES, IMAGE_RES)) / 255.0
   _ = plt.imshow(image)
   _ = plt.title(get_label_name(label))
   plt.show()
```

2. with keras layers

```
    IMAGE_RES = 229
    dataset, dataset_info = tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
    dataset_info
    test_set, training_set, validation_set = dataset['test'], dataset['train'], dataset['validation']
    get_label_name = dataset_info.features['label'].int2str



    resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_RES, IMAGE_RES),
        layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1. / 255)
    ])

    image, label = next(iter(training_set))
    _ = plt.imshow(image)
    _ = plt.title(get_label_name(label))

    result = resize_and_rescale(image)
    _ = plt.imshow(result)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Technically

Resizing layer `tf.keras.layers.Resizing` uses `tf.image.resize()` function "under the hood" ([proof](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L102)).

##### Practically

Resizing layer allows preprocessing to be built into the model to preprocess the input image data as it is fed into the model. `tf.image.resize()` function is well suited for `tf.data.Dataset.map()` method, it preprocesses the images in real-time as they are loaded.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66575616/7204581