# Keras experimental RandomFlip and RandomRotation do not work with map

Tags: tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

This code generates an error that I don't understand. Can someone explain me please?

```
import tensorflow as tf

def augment(img):
    data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
              tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
              tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
             ])
    img = tf.expand_dims(img, 0)
    return data_augmentation(img)

# generate 10 images 8x8 RGB
data = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(10, 8, 8, 3))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)

# and augment... -> bug
dataset = dataset.map(augment)

# note that the follwing works
for im in dataset:
   augment(im)
```

and a get

```
ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.
```

I tried on Google Colab and have Tensorflow 2.4.1 on my computer. Note that with resize or rescale it works (as it is in this example https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation but they didn't tried with RandomRotate even if they use it in a loop).

Comment: This doesn't make sense what you are doing. You are putting a network into the Dataset API. The purpose of the layers in tf.keras.layers.experimental is to move any data augmentation from the Dataset API to inside the graph. Then at inference time, all one has to worry about is putting in the raw data.

Comment: I tried that too but without success. What I have done is suggested in the tutorial cited above (option 2: Apply the preprocessing layers to your dataset) so I would like to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer...

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
              tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
              tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
             ])

# generate 10 images 8x8 RGB
data = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(10, 8, 8, 3))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(5)

# and augment... -> bug
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: data_augmentation(x))
```

Strange, if we use a lambda function it works, if we define a function which only calls `data_augmentation` it fails...

Comment: I tried the lambda method and got this error: Unbatching a dataset is only supported for rank >= 1. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you run .unbatch() before map?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've confused the purpose of `tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.*`. They are to be used **in conjunction** with your model. So that data augmentation is streamlined with the model it self.

In other words, these layers are a part of your model, **not** your data pipeline (as you're trying to use it with the `dataset.map` for example). If you'd like to use these layers with a `tf.data.Dataset`, here's a working example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def augment(img):
    data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
              tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
              tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
             ])    
    return data_augmentation(img)

# generate 10 images 8x8 RGB
data = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(10, 8, 8, 3))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data).batch(5)

for d in dataset:
  aug_d = augment(d)
```