# Keras bug when adding preprocessing layer to sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I created a Sequential preprocessing layer model like so:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, RandomRotation
from tensorflow.keras.utils import set_random_seed; set_random_seed(72)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(ax, ay), (qx, qy) = cifar10.load_data()
ay = keras.utils.to_categorical(ay, 10)
qy = keras.utils.to_categorical(qy, 10)
ax = ax.astype('float32'); ax /= 255;
qx = qx.astype('float32'); qx /= 255;

DA = Sequential([RandomRotation(180/360,fill_mode="nearest",interpolation="bilinear", input_shape=(32, 32, 3))])
```

I then printed the output of the first image using:

```
X=ax[0:1,:,:,:]
plt.imshow(X[0])
plt.show()

transformedX=DA(X).numpy()
plt.imshow(transformedX[0,:,:,:])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

This is the expected output. The network added a random rotation to the image.

Then, I added the preprocessing model to another sequential model including nothing but it and a Dropout layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(DA)
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

Finally, I printed the images again in the same way as before **without using the new model at all**:

```
X=ax[0:1,:,:,:]
plt.imshow(X[0])
plt.show()

transformedX=DA(X).numpy()
plt.imshow(transformedX[0,:,:,:])
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

I got this result both locally (in Spyder) and using Google Colab. [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sVJSDUjdRmAwht1ts-aArlXsKCbI3ebD?usp=sharing)'s the notebook if you want to try it out.

From here, every other time you run the program, every image will look like the original. To get this result again, I need to Restart Runtime (in Google Colab), `%reset` does not seem to work locally.

If I remove the `input_shape=(32, 32, 3)` line from the preprocessing layer, the problem does not occur. However, I was under the impression this was necessary to include in the first layer of a model.

Is this a real bug or a problem in my code?

If it is a bug, is this particular of some outdated version of Keras or Tensorflow?

Comment: transformedX=DA(X).numpy() -> transformedX=model(X).numpy() ???

Comment: `transformedX=model(X).numpy()` does result in the original image. However, even if the program was somehow interpreting `DA` as `model`, this does not explain why it still happens when you redeclare DA and run it again.

Comment: The input shape of a `Sequential` model will be inferred when you provide data to it the first time. So, you do not have to explicitly define it.

Comment: I suppose it does work without declaring the input shape, but if this is really a bug then there might be other ones when I actually use this to train a neural network. In fact, using Data Augmentation with this actually lowers the performance of the network, but that might be my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is threefold. It is related to

- How TF handle the `training` argument (or the lack thereof) passed to a layer call
- How `Dropout` layer handles `training=None`
- How TF constructs `Sequential` models

Note that my answer is based on TF v2.9.1.

---

### The `training` argument

*Some* layers, such as Dropout or RandomRotation, behave differently during training and inferencing. That's why [at their core](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L126), layers always try to identify if the call to them is made during training or not whenever they are called via `()` (syntactic sugar for `__call__`). Internally, the `training` flag is set to, *in priority order*,

> 1. `training` argument with non-None value explicitly passed to the layer call e.g., when you call the layer as `layer(inputs, training=True/False)`
> 2. `training` argument determined by this very same 4-check procedure for its parent layer in a layer call chain.
> 3. [`learning_phase`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/backend.py#L324) variable of the backend *if that variable has been set*. Checking the variable's state is done by `keras.backend.global_learning_phase_is_set()` and getting its value is done by `keras.backend.learning_phase()`.
> 4. *Default value* of `training` argument in this layer `call` signature. Note that `call ≠ __call__`. The former is a TF-defined method and the latter is one of many built-in magic methods in Python, although `__call__` implementation of base layer eventually invokes `call` at some point.

If none of the 4 checks yields a non-None value, then `training=None` is used.

RandomRotation layer only rotates images if it sees `training=True`. Your call to it failed the first three checks but passed the last thanks to `training` being defaulted to `True` in its `call` [signature](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/image_preprocessing.py#L1108). Thus, the layer saw `training=True` and behaved as expected. However, as soon as you added Dropout, everything went south so what's happening?

---

### Dropout and `training=None`

It turns out that **a call to Dropout with eventual `training=None` can actually set the state (but not the value) of the `learning_phase` variable**. This happens easily because unlike RandomRotation, Dropout has default `training=None` which provides no guard for check 4.

```
>>> keras.backend.global_learning_phase_is_set()
False
>>> _ = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.25)([1,2,3])
>>> keras.backend.global_learning_phase_is_set()
True
```

Once that happens, check 4 is essentially ignored for all subsequent calls to *any* layer: They will always see that `learning_phase` was set and use `training=learning_phase` (which defaults to 0) whenever reaching check 3. Your later calls to RandomRotation fell victim to this, causing the layer to think it was called during inference and thus returned the input as-is.

More precisely, [Dropout won't accept None for `training`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/layers/regularization/dropout.py#L104) and will directly fetch `learning_phase` regardless of its state, by calling `learning_phase()` without checking if `global_learning_phase_is_set()` first. This unchecked `learning_phase()` call will set the state for `learning_phase` in the process.

```
>>> keras.backend.global_learning_phase_is_set()
False
>>> keras.backend.learning_phase()
0
>>> keras.backend.global_learning_phase_is_set()
True
```

---

### But I did not call Dropout?

Here comes the final part, which is about the way `Sequential` adds layers to its stack. When you add the first layer that is not a [keras tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input) but has a known input shape, sequential will create an input keras tensor with that exact same shape and immediately call the layer on that tensor to secure an output keras tensor. This is possible because the input shape is already known.

```
>>> Sequential([RandomRotation(0.5)]).outputs is None
True
>>> Sequential([RandomRotation(0.5, input_shape=(2,2,1))]).outputs
[<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 2, 2, 1) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'random_rotation_7')>]
```

From there, each time you add another layer, the sequential model will check if it already has an output keras tensor (i.e., checking if the input shape is already known). If so, it will again immediately call the new layer on the current output tensor to obtain an updated one. Otherwise, the input shape is unknown, and the model defers the construction of output keras tensor until later when it is called on actual input data.

```
>>> from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
>>> from tensorflow.keras.layers import RandomRotation, Dropout
>>> class DropoutWithCount(Dropout):
...     def __init__(self, rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None, **kwargs):
...         super().__init__(rate, noise_shape, seed, **kwargs)
...         self.count = 0
...
...     def call(self, inputs, training=None):
...         self.count += 1
...         print(f"Dropout called with training={training}, call counts = {self.count}")
...         return super().call(inputs, training)
...
>>> m = Sequential([RandomRotation(0.5, input_shape=(2,2,1)), DropoutWithCount(.25)])
Dropout called with training=None, call counts = 1
>>> m = Sequential([RandomRotation(0.5, input_shape=(2,2,1))])
>>> m1 = Sequential()
>>> m1.add(m)
>>> m1.add(DropoutWithCount(.25))
Dropout called with training=None, call counts = 1
>>> m = Sequential([RandomRotation(0.5), DropoutWithCount(.25)])
>>>
```

So yes, since the input shape is known, the Dropout layer will be automatically called without any `training` argument *as soon as it is added* to sequential, which consequently sets the state for `learning_phase`.

---

### What should I do?

Always pass `training` argument properly to your model/layer calls as explicit argument checking ranks highest in precedence. Otherwise, don't pass `training`  to *any* calls but instead set global value `learning_phase` to either True or False via `keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True/False)` as this will take precedence over the default `training` values of the layers.

```
>>> from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
>>> from tensorflow.keras.layers import RandomRotation, Dropout
>>> import keras as keras
>>> import numpy as np
>>> img = np.array([[[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]])
>>> m = Sequential([RandomRotation(0.5, input_shape=(2,2,1))])
>>> m(img)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[1.6862597],
         [3.3725195]],

        [[1.6274806],
         [3.3137403]]]], dtype=float32)>
>>> m1 = Sequential()
>>> m1.add(m)
>>> m1.add(Dropout(.25))
>>> m(img)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[1.],
         [2.]],

        [[3.],
         [4.]]]], dtype=float32)>
>>> m(img, training=True)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[1.8427435],
         [3.685487 ]],

        [[1.314513 ],
         [3.1572566]]]], dtype=float32)>
>>> keras.backend.set_learning_phase(True)
>>> m(img)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2, 2, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[3.3871531],
         [3.3064234]],

        [[1.6935766],
         [1.612847 ]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not very adept in Python but I understood most of what you exemplified. I did not know that calls to a Model had a Training argument for this purpose, I will use that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at this post: [Keras experimental RandomFlip and RandomRotation do not work with map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570789/keras-experimental-randomflip-and-randomrotation-do-not-work-with-map). It may be better to use this DA as a layer or preprocessing and take out the Y rather than the layer itself. So for instance DA(X) is a one time run and then you use the output (rather than DA(X) itself) for your model(X).

Like:

```
model = DA
model.add(dropout=0.25)
```

or roughly

```
y = DA(X)  
z = model(y)
```